# C# Formatting columns when exporting data into excel

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

I know this topic has been discussed but I think it has some differences. I have dates stored in my database. So when I export data table into EXCEL, it shows like the image.

Here is the image of the EXCEL file:

[image]

I need to add only date. Not HH:MM:SS included. my code is pasted below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
worksheet.Name = "InternDetails";

for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView3.Columns.Count + 1; i++){
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView3.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; j++){
        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.FileName = "Interns";
saveFileDialog.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";

if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you need to format excel to only show the date part

Comment: Yes. But if there is any way to do that in the code?

Comment: excel is tricky, it tries to be `too` helpful sometimes.  you could set the exel column for that date as `'text` and export the date into that to stop it doing a `helpful` auto-format.

Comment: Ah. so u mean i have to edit the excel form?. that cant be done in c#?

Comment: ok, you could try to pre-append to the your date string a single `'`.  that tells excel to treat the value as explicit text and to not try auto formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,if you want to show date only.and no time,you should set the **number format**.
just look at the code like this:
`SomeCell.NumberFormat="yyyy-mm-dd"`

it will show for example:"2018-05-20"

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, for what I saw in the provided screenshot, it consist of 3 date column which is `statusdate`, `fplacementdate` and `periodcomplertion`.

Have you tried it this way?

First create a conversion function for you date.

```
public static string convertDateFormat(this string date)
{
                DateTime dateFormat = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                if (dateFormat != DateTime.MinValue)
                {
                    return String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dateFormat);
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
}
```

Then use it this way

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.Rows.Count; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView3.Columns.Count; j++){
        string formatValue = dataGridView3.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

        if( dataGridView3.Columns[j].HeaderText == "statusdate" || dataGridView3.Columns[j].HeaderText == "fplacementdate" || dataGridView3.Columns[j].HeaderText == "periodcomplertion"){
           formatValue.convertDateFormat();
        }

        worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = formatValue;
    }
}
```